# Wordpress: Adding relational data to custom post_type

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a Wordpress website for a company that likes to receive job applications from their users, on specific jobs, and I am wondering how to do this.

**My idea is to:**

- Make a custom `post_type` with jobs
- Add a contact form that relates to the current job by `id`
- When in wp-admin, on the related job, then list the job applications with details from the contact form, so my client can contact the job appliers.

**My questions are:**

- How do I add the table of job applications on the `post_type=jobs` wp-admin-page on the administration page for the current job?
- Is it best to add the contact form data as `meta_data` to the post, or in a seperate MySQL table with relations to the `post_id`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing.

1. Create a Custom Post Type "Job".
2. On front page list all job with the APPLY JOB button.
3. On clicking the Apply Job button open a pop-up with a form to apply
   for jobs.
4. Job will have a hidden field containing job id, job title.
5. When user apply save those details in a separate table say
   wp_apply_job and a email to the author of job posted.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but it's not what I need. I just need to know how to list alle the users who have applied for the specific job inside the wp-admin interface (backend), so the admin can handle the job appliers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex problem, but just what Worpress is good at. It's a CMS, a content management system.

There are multiple architectures you can use. One question is, does the applicant data need to be associated with the jobs, or with the applicant mostly?

You're correct, that you'll need to use CPTs. You can use the native Wordpress admin to manipulate CPTs.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

You might need to create a CPT for jobs and for the specific application submitted for each job. I would definitely NOT use the word "job" for the slug. Use something like "myCustomJobCPT". Wordpress slugs are globally scoped namesspaces. If you create a CPT for each submission, you can add data to the post content if you want, or you can add custom fields to the CPT post.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

If you only associate the data with the user, you can use user_meta for the data, and cross reference that with the CPT type for jobs.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta

Finally, you will want to create a way to output your functionality. You'll want to use either:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus

or Wordpress shortcodes:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Remember to encapsulate your functionality in the Wordpress page load by using action hooks. A good one is 'init' for a starting point.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Good luck!